# i am trying to learn php and following a tutorial from youtube $_SESSION is driving me crazy ..i tried everything to make it work

Tags: php, html, variables, session, global

i have declared a session_start() function in the start of both the pages but still the variable is not passing on to the session variable please help
this is where i have included my login.php

```
<?php
include("template/header.php");
include("template/content.php");
include("template/footer.php");
include("login.php");
?>
```

this my login.php file where i have passed $email variable to SESSION

```
<?php
session_start();
include("includes/connection.php");
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $email= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
    $pass= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pass']);
    $select_user = "select * from users where user_email= '$email' AND 
    user_pass='$pass' AND status='verified'";

    $query = mysqli_query($con,$select_user);
    $check_user= mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if($check_user===1){
        $_SESSION['usermail']=$email;

        echo "<script>window.open('home.php','_self')</script>";

    } else {

        echo "<script>alert('incorrect details try again')</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

and this is where i have tried to access the session variable but it says undefined:usermail but i dont understand i am giving the session_start() at the beginning and have checked that $email is successfully getting its value from the database then why this is not working

```
<?php
session_start();
include("includes/connection.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Welcome User!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/home_style.css" media="all"/>
</head>
<body>
<!--container starts-->
<div class="container">
   <!--header wrapper starts here-->
   <div id="head_wrap">
       <!--header starts-->
       <div id="header">
          <ul id="menu">
              <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="members.php">Members</a></li>
              <strong>Topics:</strong>
              <?php
               $get_topics = "select * from topics";
               $run_topics= mysqli_query($con,$get_topics);

              while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_topics)){

                  $topic_id = $row['topic_id'];
                  $topic_title = $row['topic_name'];
                echo "<li><a href='topic.php? 
   topic=$topic_id'>$topic_title</a></li>";
              }

              ?>

          </ul>
          <form method="get" action="results.php" id="form1">
              <input type="text" name="user_query" placeholder="search a 
   topic"/>
              <input type="submit" name="search" value="search"/>
          </form>

       </div><!--header ends-->
   </div><!--head wrap ends-->

   <!--content area starts-->
   <div class="content">
    <!--user timeline starts here-->
      <div id="user_timeline">
        <div id="user_details">
         <?php
          $user=$_SESSION['usermail'];
            var_dump($_SESSION);
          $get_user="select * from users where user_email='$user'";
          $run_user= mysqli_query($con,$get_user);
          $row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_user);

          $user_id= $row['user_id'];
          $user_name= $row['user_name'];
          $user_country= $row['user_country'];
          $user_image= $row['user_image'];
          $register_date= $row['user_reg_date'];
          $last_login= $row['user_last_login'];

          $user_posts="select * from posts where user_id='$user_id'";
          $run_posts = mysqli_query($con,$user_posts);
          $posts =mysqli_num_rows($run_posts);

          //getting the number of unread messages
          $sel_msg = "select * from messages where receiver='$user_id' AND 
          status='unread' ORDER by 1 DESC";

          $run_msg = mysqli_query($con,$sel_msg);

          $count_msg = mysqli_num_rows($run_msg);

          echo "
            <center>
            <img src='users/default.png' width='200' height='200'?>
            </center>
            <dev id='user_mention'>
            <p><strong>Country:</strong>$user_country</p>
            <p><strong>Last Login:</strong>$last_login</p>
            <p><strong>Member Since:</strong>$register_date</p>

            <p><a href='my_messages.php?inbox&u_id=$user_id'>Messages 
           ($count_msg)</a></p>
            <p><a href='edit_profile.php?u_id=$user_id'>Edit my account</a> 
            </p>
            <p><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></p>
            </div>

          ";
          ?>
          </div><!--user details ends here-->

      </div><!--user timeline ends here-->

      </div><!--content area ends-->

      </div><!--container ends-->

      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: i have noticed that $_SESSION['usermail'] exists only inside the if statement and it just dosent work outside of the if

Comment: Inside **which** if?

Comment: in login.php page where i check if(isset($_POST['login'])) ..here SESSION variables behaves as a local behaviour  i tried doing echo $_SESSION['usermail'] outside if statement on the same page nothin happens. i get error undefined index:usermail

Comment: That means this line `if($check_user===1){` isn't returning `true`. Try checking the value for `$check_user` before the if statement

Comment: i checked $check_user is returning 1,maybe its a php.ini problem i have searched on google im using Xampp server and it is installed in my c drive maybe i need to tweak something to enable session..sorry im new to this .my session.save_path is 'C:\xampp\tmp' and session.auto_start is set to 0

Comment: hi i found the solution ,i need to start a new session on the index page as well.After i changed session.auto_start to 1 my code started working thats how i figured it  out that i need another seession_start() on index.php. yaaay!